# How can I pass a jQuery variable to PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to dynamically change the options of the second selector by what the user choses in the previous one. But it only gives a syntax error.

````
    </script>
    <select name="budova" id="idBudova">
        <option value="" selected="selected">Vyberte...</option>
        @foreach($budovy as $budova)
            <option>{{$budova->nazov}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select><br>

    <script>
        $("#idBudova").change(function () {
            if ($('#idBudova').val() >= 1) {
                $('#miestnost').show();
                <?php $miestnosti = Miestnosti::where("id_budovy", "=", $('#idBudova').val())->get(); ?>
            } else {                                                    //here is the mistake 
                                                                      //how to make php see the variable
                $('#miestnost').hide();
            }
        });
    </script>

    <div hidden id="miestnost">
        <select name="miestnost" id="idMiestnost">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Vyberte...</option>
            @foreach($miestnosti as $miestnost)
                <option>{{$miestnost->nazov}}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select></div>```
````

Comment: You can't mix PHP and JavaScript like this. You especially can't put JavaScript in the middle of your PHP. Remember the PHP script runs *first* and is long gone by the time the JavaScript runtime takes over. There is no going back to PHP. There is no JavaScript in PHP. `$('#idBudova').val()` makes zero sense to PHP.

Comment: It's time to learn about AJAX.

Comment: What can I do with AJAX could you just tell me what can I try to do?

Comment: AJAX allows JavaScript to make arbitrary calls back to your PHP application. In this case the program flow is PHP -> JavaScript -> PHP. Otherwise you're stuck with just PHP -> JavaScript and no return path.

Comment: Since it's 2020 and bashing around with jQuery only gets you so far, you may want to look at using a front-end framework like Vue or React to make a component for this.

Comment: I am doing this through Laravel. Is there any possibility?

Comment: Laravel is your back-end framework. You can use AJAX or Vue or whatever on the front-end. There's no constraints.